# React Context in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am creating context to handle authentication in typescript app. I have written this `AuthProvider.ts`

```
/*-- Imports --*/

/*--  AuthContextType interface and defaults -- */

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(contextDefaults);

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  const isLoggedIn = !!user;

  const login = (data: User) => {
    setUser(data);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContextType.Provider value={{ user, isLoggedIn, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContextType.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Then I am wrapping App with this AuthProvider;

```
/* --- imports ---*/

const App = () => {
  return (
      <AuthProvider>
        <div>App</div>
      </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This code is giving errors and when I write same code in javascript app it is working fine.

`AuthContext.ts` Errors

[image]

`App.js` Error
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that you've used: `AuthContextType.Provider` when you mean `AuthContext.Provider`?

AuthContextType is a Typescript type, not a react context object.

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  .... 
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isLoggedIn, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Does this work?

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.